# Unset Session Array With Ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I Use Ajax Request For Delete Item From Session Array,With This Code :

My Ajax Function :

```
function session_delete(item) {

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/session_delete.php",
        data: {item:item},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

       alert(data.length);

    }
  })

}
```

session_delete.php :

```
    <?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

$item=$_POST['item'];

unset($_SESSION['user'][$item]);

echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']);

}
```

This Code Work Good And Unset Array Item In Server Side, But When Json Data Return To Client Side ,Show Previous `$_session['user']` Value(not Update) And When Reload Page Or Repeat Request Show True Value

Comment: you're only unsetting the`item` of `$_SESSION['user']`, not the actual session. to unset it, use `unset($_SESSION['user'])` you don't have to pass a session identifier to php. the cookie is sent in all http request and read by the server.

Comment: question is a bit ambiguous... works good but doesn't work. Not totally clear what objective is, or what is showing true